# Cannot map property in mapper

Tags: c#

I have created a PropertyMapper which maps property from source to destination.

```
public static void PropertyMap<T, U>(T source, U destination)
    where T : class, new()
    where U : class, new()
{
    List<PropertyInfo> sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();
    List<PropertyInfo> destinationProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
    {
        PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name);

        if (destinationProperty != null)
        {
            try
            {
                destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);                
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass in a source object which contains `{int,string,customobject}` I am able to map `{int and string }` but not my 'customobject'. When looping through the source properties when the counter reaches to `customobject` datatype i get an exception.What I need to do is put it in recursion and map those properties again.So I guess I'am missing a filter check .

Comment: don't you want to use automapper?

Comment: No I am trying to implement my own

Comment: It would help if you told us what exception you get

Comment: This could be quite challenging task if you want to handle all scenarios: think of arrays of complex objects and complex objects that do not have a default constructor. So the question now is how far do you want to get with this : basically have a well defined problem before looking for a solution. If you don't want to use existing tools for this task then you should very well define the scenarios that you want to support.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Should I then specifically check for that propertytype in the function ?? That would beat the purpose of generic function though.

Comment: There are 3 cases that you need to handle: 1. simple scalar types (you've already done that in your code), 2. complex types and 3. arrays (which of course once again can be of simple or complex types). And of course a recursion, because the object graph could go deeper at arbitrary levels and on each level repeat those 3 scenarios. So as I said, this is not an easy task especially if you want a generic solution that will work for all classes that you throw at it. If this was a one-liner, tools such as AutoMapper would have never existed.

Comment: And not to mention that if you are using Reflection on each property get and set you are basically hurting very bad the performance of your application. In a full blown solution to this problem (especially if you consider using such code in production) you will have to think about creating dynamic lambda expressions and compiling them to code which will be cached for each property to avoid paying the price of Reflection every time.

Comment: I note your algorithm potentially runs in `O(n^2)` time because the `.Find` method enumerates over every property. You could optimize this to `O(n)` by storing property names in a hashtable for `O(1)` lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple implementation that will handle complex object properties (with a default constructor obviously):

```
public static void PropertyMap<T, U>(T source, U destination)
    where T : class, new()
    where U : class, new()
{
    List<PropertyInfo> sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();
    List<PropertyInfo> destinationProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties().ToList<PropertyInfo>();
    PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationProperties.Find(item => item.Name == sourceProperty.Name);

    if (destinationProperty != null)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
        {
            if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == destinationProperty.PropertyType &&
                simpleTypes.Contains(sourceProperty.PropertyType) &&
                simpleTypes.Contains(destinationProperty.PropertyType))
            {
                // set the value of the simple type directly
                destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }
            else
            {
                // complex object => we start by instantiating it which will
                // of course crash if the target type doesn't have a 
                // default constructor
                var destInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(destinationProperty.PropertyType);
                destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, destInstance, null);

                // recurse down the object graph
                PropertyMap(sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), destInstance);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static readonly Type[] simpleTypes = new[]
{
    typeof(string),
    typeof(ushort),
    typeof(uint),
    typeof(ulong),
    typeof(short),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(long),
    typeof(float),
    typeof(decimal),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(TimeSpan),
    // Make sure I didn't forgot some other simple types that you
    // would like to handle
};
```

Of course this solution doesn't handle arrays. As I already noted in the comments section having a full blown implementation of an object mapper would require much more than that. and we are not even talking about any performance here. Use this code only for some fun and learning purposes but never in production especially if you care about performance. In this case you should consider using Reflection Emit to generate dynamic code for reading and setting property values of different types (which you should cache) and then directly invoke those dynamically generated methods. That's how some ORMs like Dapper work.